# VBA FileDialog saves powerpoint as .ppt instead of .pptx

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint with a couple macros: one that allows you to load some data from a Word, and another one that exports the PowerPoint to the same location where the Word was. This is the latter:

```
Sub export()
    Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
    Dim strMyFile As String
    Dim ppPres As Presentation
    
    Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With dlgSaveAs
        .InitialFileName = path & "Exported without macros - " & company & " (((insert date)))"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strMyFile = .SelectedItems(1)
            'MsgBox strMyFile
            ActivePresentation.SaveAs strMyFile, 1
            '-- save your file to strMyFile here
        Else
            'MsgBox "No file selected."
           '-- The user pressed Cancel.
        End If
    End With
    Set dlgSaveAs = Nothing    
End Sub
```

To be honest, I didn´t wrote this code. I found it months ago and adapted it and I dont know how it really works.
The issue is that when the 'Save As' FileDialog opens, the file extension seems to be ok:
[image: 'SaveAs' FileDialog]

But after pressing 'save' the file gets saved as a .ppt:
[image: Saved PowerPoint]
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs strMyFile, 1
```

to this:

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs strMyFile, 24
```

or to

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs strMyFile, ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
```